# Change polymorphic type in ruby

Tags: ruby, polymorphism

(I am using the gosu gem to draw to the screen.)

I am working on a file tree in ruby (not rails). Right now I have something like this:

```
class FileTree
  @files = []
end

class Folder
  @assets = []

  def left_click
    # Open or close
  end
end

file_tree = FileTree.new
folder1 = Folder.new
folder2 = Folder.new
file_tree.files << folder1 << folder2
```

Now the folders get drawn to the screen, and the user should be able to click them to open/close them, and view the assets that are inside. I am not sure the best way to handle this change of state.

My first thought was to have a bool `@opened`, and just check that to determine if assets are `@visible` (another bool). However, I would like to replace the conditionals with polymorphism.

So I made `ClosedFolder` and `OpenFolder` classes that inherit from Folder, and then just initialized `ClosedFolder`s into my `FileTree`. However, now I need to click the folder and have it change to an `OpenFolder` - but the file_tree doesn't know about the changed object and I have basically had to do a weird swap to get it in place.

I then tried adding `@type` to `Folder`, making modules of ClosedFolder and OpenFolder, and then making methods that do this:

```
class Folder
  include ClosedFolder, OpenFolder

  def left_click
    public_send("#{@type}_left_click")
  end
end

module ClosedFolder
  def closed_folder_left_click
    @type = :open_folder
    @assets = get_files
  end
end

module OpenFolder
  def open_folder_left_click
    @type = :closed_folder
    @assets = []
  end
end
```

When I ran this code, my CPU shot through the roof. I also don't like naming every method after the module/type.

So, how do I handle this problem? Are conditional checks the way to go? Would love to be able to just call `left_click` on my asset and have it use the method in the correct object.

Comment: Managing state with inheritance seems overkill. Use inheritance or duck typing if you have multiple objects that can support the same interface and you wish to use them interchangeably. That doesn't really seem to be the case here. To think about it another way, when you open a box is it a different box? No, the box is the same, the state has just changed. If modelling a box, you could use a variable or accessor to manage that state. Same goes here.

Comment: I'm not sure why your "CPU shot through the roof"... I tried a variation of your code and it seemed to play nice.  As discussed, the solution is a little over-engineered but it does work. You could have done that, in fact, with just private methods in the Folder class, the modules don't add any value.

Comment: Yah I am thinking the CPU problem must have been a different change. I used the modules to keep it separate, but then since I had to name them so distinctly it really didn't add anything. Was just trying different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more thought, this just wants to be a state_machine, which is nearly like a case or branching ifs. However, we were able to implement a way to handle this without conditionals that feels pretty good:

```
class Folder
  def initialize(name)
    @name   = name
    @state  = ClosedFolderState.new(self)
  end

  attr_reader :name
  attr_accessor :state

  def pretty_name
    "#{@state.icon} #{@name}"
  end

  def left_click
    @state.left_click
  end
end

class ClosedFolderState
  def initialize(folder)
    @folder = folder
  end

  def icon
    '+'
  end

  def left_click
    @folder.state = OpenFolderState.new(@folder)
  end
end

class OpenFolderState
  def initialize(folder)
    @folder = folder
  end

  def icon
    '-'
  end

  def left_click
    @folder.state = ClosedFolderState.new(@folder)
  end
end
```

This may be overkill, but this seems to meet our goal of just seeing if we can move away from conditionals, and here using a decorator seems to work. I am not saying this would be everyone's preferred solution, but I think this answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

Just seems like a very complicated way to avoid some simple conditionals.

If it were my project I'd be going down this route...

```
class Folder

  def initialize
    @assets = []
    @open = false
  end

  def left_click
    @open = !@open
    @assets = @open ? get_files : []
  end

end
```

Comment: Well, i do know how to make this work with conditionals. I was just wanting to see if there was a clean way to make this work without them. More for the exercise than anything else. But it sounds like there is no clean way, conditionals are the cleanest way to model what I have.

Comment: Yes, the state-change is what makes what you're trying to do so difficult. There is (AFAIK) no way to change an object's class. If the class had been a stable and immutable component in the design that wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I forgot that there is also a 'pretty_name' method that changes depending on the state, so there is one more place I would have to ask what the state is to determine behavior. I might look at rails later to see how they handle polymorphism and type, but I think that will be way more over-engineered than even the solutions we have.